# TFS - Folder Management

Tags: c#

I am new to TFS and I have following problem.

This is how my Folder structure looks alike:

```
Project1
  |_
    Test1
      |_
        Test2
          |_
             text.txt
```

What I need is this:

```
Project1
  |_
    Test2
      |_
        text.txt
```

Basicall I have to move Test2 folder under Project1 and then I have to remove Test1 folder.

I tried that so in my branch but once I merged back to main it seems I lost the connection between files and their version and main always showed me error that folder already exists.

I did a undo pending changes on main. Now I am waiting.

What can I do to solve this properly?

Comment: Can you give more details on the error you get when merge, at what point do you get it. Make sure you don't have weirdness in workspace mappings. You can try to merge each part (move and delete) separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the "Move..." option.

- Right click on Test2 and `Move` it from "$/Project1/Test1/Test2" to "$/Project1/Test2".
- Check in the change
- Right click on Test1 and `Delete`
- Check in the change

(I've suggested two checkins for this because TFS is very bad at handling mixtures of renames and deletes, and as Test2 is inside Test1, you may encounter problems trying to delete and rename in one step)

Comment: I did that all just without always checking in the changes in my branch. Once I try to merge with main it crashes.

Comment: tfs is very poor at handling renames and deletes. This is worsened if you try to check on multiple changes at once, and doubly worsened if you try to merge from a branch. Try making the change as several simple check-ins, and merging one by one. If that fails, then you may have to apply the changes manually to Main rather than trusting TFS to get them right now that it is confused.